# Right writing of While loop

Tags: procedural-programming, infinite-loop, condition

Help me pls write While loop correctly. I have next code:

```
Po[r1_, r2_] = (StruveH[0, Sqrt[r1^2 + r2^2 - 2*r1*r2*0.9]] - BesselY[0, Sqrt[r1^2 + r2^2 - 2*r1*r2*0.9]]);

Pmax = 1;
Pcurrent = 1;

While[Pmax/Pcurrent < 3,
 For[r1 = 0.1, r1 < 10, r1 += 0.1,
  For[r2 = 0.1, r2 < 10, r2 += 0.1,
   If[Po[r1, r2] > Pmax, Pmax = Po[r1, r2]; Print["Pmax= ", Pmax], 
    Pcurrent = Po[r1, r2]; Print["Pcurrent= ", Pcurrent]]]]]
```

I would like to finish the calculations and print the data when While condition (Pmax/Pcurrent < 3) is reached.

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Po[r1_, r2_] = (StruveH[0, Sqrt[r1^2 + r2^2 - 2*r1*r2*9/10]] - 
    BesselY[0, Sqrt[r1^2 + r2^2 - 2*r1*r2*9/10]]);

{values, {pts}} = Reap[
   Table[
    Pmax = 1;
    Pcurrent = 1;
    r2 = 0.1;
    While[
     Pmax/Pcurrent < 3 && r2 < 10, po = Po[r1, r2]; 
     If[po > Pmax, Pmax = po, Pcurrent = po];
     r2 += 0.1];
    Sow[{r1, r2}]; Pmax/Pcurrent,
    {r1, 0.1, 10, 0.1}]];

Graphics[{
  Red,
  AbsolutePointSize[2],
  Point[pts]},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@
    {HoldForm@r1, HoldForm@r2}),
 AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]